# Problem with layout productpage

Tags: layout, product-page, magento-1.9.1.1

I have a problem with the layout of the productpage.
I upgraded from magento 1.9.1.0 to magento 1.9.1.1
But now the layout is gone.
This is how it used to be:
http://www.etk-mood.nl/shop/catalogus/inbouw/downlighters-led/caim-led.html

And this is the new installation:
http://testshop.etkserver.nl/catalogus/inbouw/downlighters-led/caim-led.html

**1.    GLOBAL DESCRIPTION MISSES**
The global description does not appear next to the image. I have compared the frontend/shopper/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml’s and they are identical.

```
<div class="product-shop-info">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>

        <div class="short-description"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, ($_product->getDescription()), 'description') ?></div>
                <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $this->getDescription() ?>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
```

**2.    TABS**

In de new website the tab content of ALL the tabs appears at once, instead of when you click the relevant tab.

**3.    NO DESCRIPTION IN TABLE**

As you can see, the grouped table misses the second column, the Description.
If I look in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
There still is this code that used to work:

```
<table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Omschrijving') ?></th>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
```

It is kind of urgent, I hope you can help me.
THank you.